# Nuxt - wall of errors when installing Sass

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, nuxt.js

I'm not very confident with NPM/CMD-based dev and I'm trying to add Sass to a Nuxt installation.

As per the Sass docs, I did this via

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader
```

But when I restarted my Nuxt server via `yarn dev`, I then got this wall of errors, which means very little. I then uninstalled Sass via

```
npm uninstall node-sass sass-loader
```

...and I can once again start my Nuxt server without issue. What on earth happened?

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 64 errors

These dependencies were not found:

* core-js/modules/es6.array.filter.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.array.find.js in ./.nuxt/client.js
* core-js/modules/es6.array.from.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator.js in ./.nuxt/client.js
* core-js/modules/es6.array.map.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.array.slice.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.date.to-string.js in ./.nuxt/utils.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.function.name.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.object.assign.js in ./.nuxt/client.js
* core-js/modules/es6.object.get-own-property-descriptor.js in ./.nuxt/index.js, ./node_modules/ufo/dist/index.mjs
* core-js/modules/es6.object.keys.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/utils.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.object.to-string.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js and 2 others
* core-js/modules/es6.promise.js in ./.nuxt/client.js
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.constructor.js in ./.nuxt/utils.js
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.match.js in ./node_modules/ufo/dist/index.mjs
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.replace.js in ./.nuxt/index.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.search.js in ./.nuxt/utils.js, ./node_modules/ufo/dist/index.mjs
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.split.js in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--2-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-build-indicator.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&, ./node_modules/ufo/dist/index.mjs
* core-js/modules/es6.regexp.to-string.js in ./.nuxt/utils.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/es6.string.ends-with.js in ./node_modules/ufo/dist/index.mjs
* core-js/modules/es6.string.includes.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js
* core-js/modules/es6.string.iterator.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js and 1 other
* core-js/modules/web.dom.iterable.js in ./.nuxt/client.js, ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-link.client.js and 1 other
errors

To install them, you can run: npm install --save core-js/modules/es6.array.filter.js core-js/modules/es6.array.find.js core-js/modules/es6.array.from.js core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator.js core-jerrors 12:15:27  s/modules/es6.array.map.js core-js/modules/es6.array.slice.js core-js/modules/es6.date.to-string.js core-js/modules/es6.function.name.js core-js/modules/es6.object.assign.js core-js/modules/es6.objerrors 12:15:27  ect.get-own-property-descriptor.js core-js/modules/es6.object.keys.js core-js/modules/es6.object.to-string.js core-js/modules/es6.promise.js core-js/modules/es6.regexp.constructor.js core-js/moduleerrors 12:15:27  s/es6.regexp.match.js core-js/modules/es6.regexp.replace.js core-js/modules/es6.regexp.search.js core-js/modules/es6.regexp.split.js core-js/modules/es6.regexp.to-string.js core-js/modules/es6.strierrors 12:15:27  ng.ends-with.js core-js/modules/es6.string.includes.js core-js/modules/es6.string.iterator.js core-js/modules/es6.string.repeat.js core-js/modules/es6.string.starts-with.js core-js/modules/es6.symberrors 12:15:27  ol.js core-js/modules/es7.array.includes.js core-js/modules/es7.object.entries.js core-js/modules/es7.object.get-own-property-descriptors.js core-js/modules/es7.promise.finally.js core-js/modules/ws/modules/es6.arreb.dom.iterable.js
rty-descriptor.js
i Waiting for file changes
es6.regexp.re
       core-js/modul
i Memory usage: 809 MB (RSS: 931 MB)
ct.entries.js cor
i Listening on: http://localhost:3000/

 WARN  Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
```

Comment: So, did @fevid answered your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try installing how the nuxt js documents say [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/configuration#pre-processors)

```
npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader@10 fibers
```

Comment: This is usually because of Webpack versions (v4 vs v5), or postcss or alike.